# Why for loop is iterating more than given condition in my Java program

Tags: java, for-loop, factorial

I am trying to find factorize of an integer with for loop(with number of iteration) but the output is more than the specified number of loops.

I write the same code on my laptop but there it is working fine with specific number of iteration and not exceeding.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n=5;
        for(int a=1; a<=n; a++ ) {
            n=a*n;
            System.out.println(n);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
5
10
30
120
600
3600
25200
201600
1814400
18144000
199584000
-1899959296
```

Comment: Probably because it changes with every iteration.

Comment: You are increasing the stop condition in every iteration. The loop has stopped only because `int` has max value.

Comment: Stop condition is `a <= n`, but `n` is set to `n = a * n` each time.

Comment: I think it should be `a<n`, otherwise you're doing `5*1*2*3*4*5`.

Comment: Also important to note: the programm only stops because an integer overflow happens.

Comment: @CSGO that 'll cause the same issue -> n is being altered inside the loop

Comment: @Stultuske right. Then `n=1` and `a<= 5` will do,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like:

```
1*n = n
2*n = 2n

... ... ...

(n-1)*n = n(n-1)
n*n = n^2
```

So, partial result is like, `a*n` where `n` is fixed and `a` is increasing by `1` till `n`. In your code, you put `n=a*n` which is meaning that your `n` is updating on each iteration. Do not update the value of `n` that is remove the line which contain `n=a*n`. Actually, you do not require a `counter` variable too. Just print the value of `a*n` into the print statement. Therefore, the solution could be

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n=5;
        for(int a=1; a<=n; a++ ) {
            System.out.println(a*n);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are changing the value of n in the loop, so it iterates more. Use another variable to count loops, e.g.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n=5, counter=5;
        for(int a=1; a<=counter; a++ ) {
            n=a*n;
            System.out.println(n);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: better yet, don't use any variable: a <= 5; 'll work just as well. Seeing as you don't need to update it, nor need to use it in another part of the code, there's no need for the variable

Comment: you could declare `n` inside the init expression: it isn't used outside

Comment: @AndrewTobilko nothing is used outside of the loop

Comment: public class Test {
public static void main(String args[]) {
 int n=5;
 int counter=n;

 for(int a=1; a<=counter; a++ ) {
  n=a*n;
 System.out.println(n);
 }
}
}

Answer (score 0):

//Thanks for your responses with your help i was able to figure out the issue
//This is how i over come the problem to limit the iteration/

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int n=5;
    int counter=n;

    for(int a=1; a<=counter; a++ ) {
        n=a*n;
    System.out.println(n);
    }
}
}
```